# how to uninstall cli tool on mac that was downloaded via npm

Tags: npm, command-line-interface

I originally installed the `cdktf` cli on my mac using `npm install --global cdktf-cli@latest`. I now want to uninstall the cdktf cli, but even after I run `npm uninstall --global @cdktf-cli@latest``` and get the following output:

```
npm uninstall --global @cdktf-cli@latest

up to date, audited 1 package in 125ms

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

, and I then run `cdktf --help`, I still get the following output, showing the tool is still installed:

```
cdktf --help
cdktf

Commands:
  cdktf init                Create a new cdktf project from a template.
  cdktf get                 Generate CDK Constructs for Terraform providers and
                            modules.
  cdktf convert             Converts a single file of HCL configuration to CDK
                            for Terraform. Takes the file to be converted on
                            stdin.
  cdktf deploy [stacks...]  Deploy the given stacks             [aliases: apply]
  cdktf destroy [stacks..]  Destroy the given stacks
  cdktf diff [stack]        Perform a diff (terraform plan) for the given stack
                                                                 [aliases: plan]
  cdktf list                List stacks in app.
  cdktf login               Retrieves an API token to connect to Terraform Cloud
                            or Terraform Enterprise.
  cdktf synth               Synthesizes Terraform code for the given app in a
                            directory.                     [aliases: synthesize]
  cdktf watch [stacks..]    [experimental] Watch for file changes and
                            automatically trigger a deploy
  cdktf output [stacks..]   Prints the output of stacks       [aliases: outputs]
  cdktf debug               Get debug information about the current project and
                            environment
  cdktf provider            A set of subcommands that facilitates provider
                            management
  cdktf completion          generate completion script

Options:
      --version                   Show version number                  [boolean]
      --disable-plugin-cache-env  Dont set TF_PLUGIN_CACHE_DIR automatically.
                                  This is useful when the plugin cache is
                                  configured differently. Supported using the
                                  env CDKTF_DISABLE_PLUGIN_CACHE_ENV.
                                                      [boolean] [default: false]
      --log-level                 Which log level should be written. Only
                                  supported via setting the env CDKTF_LOG_LEVEL
                                                                        [string]
  -h, --help                      Show help                            [boolean]

Options can be specified via environment variables with the "CDKTF_" prefix
(e.g. "CDKTF_OUTPUT")
```

Does anyone know how I can remove the cdktf cli for good, such that when I try to run `cdktf --help` I'll get something like "no tool found".

Comment: It's wired if you can't unintsall a npm global package installed by npm. But try use `which` to see where the location of this command is.  In your terminal,  input `which cdktf`, and check the result.

Comment: And try this command `npm uninstall --global cdktf-cli`, it looks like there is an extra `@` in your command

Comment: Thanks - running ```npm uninstall --global cdktf-cli``` worked

Answer (score 0):

```
npm uninstall -g cdktf-cli
```

I faced the same issue, but somehow, this command will uninstall global cdktf-cli from your machine